# Reading the list items Sharepoint 2010 client object model

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I have a list where I am storing the image URLs and I am trying to read list of items and display the images on the page. For that I wrote the script something like below....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewItem()
    {
        var myQueryString = '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Anchor" /><Value 

Type="Boolean">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>'; 

        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('AnchorImageList');
        var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        myquery.set_viewXml(myQueryString); 

        myItems = list.getItems(myquery);


        context.load(myItems, 'Include(Title,ImageURL)');
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), 

Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
    }
    function success() 
    {

        var LinkURL= "";
        var ImageURL="";
        var ListEnumerator = this.myItems.getEnumerator();
        while(ListEnumerator.moveNext())
        {
            var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
            LinkURL = currentItem.get_item('Title') ;
            ImageURL= currentItem.get_item('ImageURL');
            document.write('<img src="' + ImageURL+ '"+>');
            alert(LinkURL);

        }

    }
    function failed(sender, args) 
    {
        alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="Javascript:ViewItem();">View Items</a>
```

In my CAML query I am trying to filter items which are tagged yes for "Anchor?"(yes/no column).

But I am seeing all the results even though I tagged few items not to display. What I am doing wrong here. Please someone help me. Also,after the images are loaded on the page, the page is still showing the wheel as if it is processing something. Do I need to do something for this?

Comment: +1 good question/reasonable sample. Side note on question quality: there is no need to add thank you notes (upvote/accept/comment instead) and signature as it rarely adds value to the post.

Comment: check your caml query using U2U Caml Builder

Comment: I wrote the query using the u2u builder only and the query returns proper results when i execute it there. I am not sure why the same query is not working from Client object Model.

Answer (score 3):

try this one:

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Anchor" />
        <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

in case if it doesn't work for you, follow next steps:

1. Create a list view using standard functionality.
2. Open it at SharePoint Designier and just copy CAML query from the code.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Query` tags from the CAML query stored in `myQueryString`. The tags are added implicitly when the query is run.

It's tripped me up before, too. The insidious thing about it is that the query won't ever fail outright; sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, making it a pain to debug.

Comment: Thanks CBono. I tried different ways and it did not really work out. I am using Dataview webpart now. So far it gave me the output that i wanted. I will be expanding it to get more desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you use just single quotes in your CAML query it will work.  Mixing double and single quotes jacks up the query for some reason.  Hope that helps.